# tesseract-ocrにて「make training」を行うとエラーが発生する。

Tags: google-colaboratory, tesseract

tesseract-ocrをgit cloneし、make traningによる再学習を行おうとしたところ、下記のエラーが発生します。

コマンド：

```
!make training MODEL_NAME=foo DATA_DIR=/data TESSDATA=content/tesseract/tesstrain/tessdata GROUND_TRUTH_DIR=data/foo-ground-truth
```

エラー：

```
tesseract data/foo-ground-truth/keller_heinrich01_1854_0198_002.tif data/foo-ground-truth/keller_heinrich01_1854_0198_002 --psm 13 lstm.train
Error opening data file /usr/local/share/tessdata/eng.traineddata
Please make sure the TESSDATA_PREFIX environment variable is set to your "tessdata" directory.
Failed loading language 'eng'
Tesseract couldn't load any languages!
Could not initialize tesseract.
Makefile:225: recipe for target 'data/foo-ground-truth/keller_heinrich01_1854_0198_002.lstmf' failed
make: *** [data/foo-ground-truth/keller_heinrich01_1854_0198_002.lstmf] Error 1
```

環境はgoogle colabです。
エラー内容のパスの位置には、eng.traineddataを配置してあるのですが、なぜか上記エラーが発生してしまいます。
また、「export」でパスを通そうとしたところ、なぜかパスが設定されません。colabの仕様か何かなのでしょうか？

どなたかご教示いただければ幸いです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: `!export PATH=...` とすると、その結果は次のコマンドまで保存されません（`!` を使うと行ごとに [シェルが立ち上がります](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45787827/3240599) ）。`%env` を使うとnotebook [自身のプロセスで環境変数を設定できる](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53311791/3240599) ようですが、これは試しましたか？

Comment: 加えて、エラーメッセージでは `TESSDATA_PREFIX` に `tessdata/` へのパスを設定するように指示があります。この変数を使って実行した結果があれば教えてください。

Comment: sei0oさん、ご回答いただきありがとうございます！

`!export path=... `とその後に実行するコマンドは、別のコードに分けて順番に実行しました。また、`export` → `echo path`の順序で実行したところ、設定したパスが表示されませんでした...

Comment: また、optionで`TESSDATA_PREFIX=tessdata/`のパスを設定したところ、それを無視して、`/usr/local/share/tessdata/eng.traineddataを見に行ってしまっていました。

以上、よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: `%env`でパスを設定することができました。ですが、エラーは相変わらずです。

Comment: `+ tesseract data/foo-ground-truth/novalis_ofterdingen_1802_0232_013.tif data/foo-ground-truth/novalis_ofterdingen_1802_0232_013 --psm 13 lstm.train
Error opening data file content/tesseract/tesstrain/eng.traineddata
Please make sure the TESSDATA_PREFIX environment variable is set to your "tessdata" directory.
Failed loading language 'eng'
Tesseract couldn't load any languages!
Could not initialize tesseract.
Makefile:225: recipe for target 'data/foo-ground-mtruth/novalis_ofterdingen_1802_0232_013.lstmf' failed

Comment: make: *** [data/foo-ground-truth/novalis_ofterdingen_1802_0232_013.lstmf] Error 1`

Comment: 一応パスは設定できているようですね。 `content/tesseract/tesstrain/` というフォルダは存在していますか？（`/content` ではない？）

Comment: 存在しています。フォルダ内に「eng.traineddata」を配置してあります・・・

Comment: `/content/tesseract/tesstrain/eng.traineddata `

Comment: じゃあもう、 `/usr/local/share/tessdata` にコピーしちゃうとか…（汗